# Dynamically change the icon of an IconButton from an external class

Tags: flutter

I have this floating button which I want to change the icon dynamically based on the icon received from an external class.

Here:
`child: Icon(widget.icon, size: 50, color: themeProvider.titleColor)`

```
class TaskButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final IconData? icon;
  const TaskButton({super.key, this.icon});

  @override
  State<TaskButton> createState() => _TaskButtonState();
}

class _TaskButtonState extends State<TaskButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Positioned(
        bottom: 16.0,
        right: 16.0,
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        child: Builder(
          builder: (context) => FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              [...]
            },
            backgroundColor: themeProvider.selectedColor,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
            ),
            child: Icon(widget.icon, size: 50, color: themeProvider.titleColor),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Then, from an external class, I try to construct the TaskButton by telling it an icon that changes based on the current index of the tabController.

Here:
`TaskButton(icon: getIconForTab(_tabController.index))`

```
class MainHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainHome({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainHome> createState() => _MainHomeState();
}

class _MainHomeState extends State<MainHome>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Scaffold(
        [...]
          bottom: TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              labelColor: themeProvider.selectedColor,
              dividerColor: Colors.transparent,
              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
              tabs: const [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.task_alt_rounded)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.alarm_add_rounded)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.edit_document)),
              ]),
        ),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: const [
                GoalsTab(),
                AlarmsTab(),
                CheckTab(),
              ],
            ),
            TaskButton(
              icon: getIconForTab(_tabController.index),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}

IconData getIconForTab(int index) {
  switch (index) {
    case 0:
      return Icons.add;
    case 1:
      return Icons.alarm_add_rounded;
    case 2:
      return Icons.edit_document;
    default:
      return Icons.add;
  }
}
```

I've tried handling the state, but I can't get the TaskButton to rebuild every time it receives an icon.

The icon always stays fixed with the first icon received during construction, so when I select or change by sliding from one tab to another, the TaskButton icon stays fixed.

```
class _TaskButtonState extends State<TaskButton> {
  late IconData? currentIcon;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    currentIcon = widget.icon;
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant TaskButton oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.icon != oldWidget.icon) {
      setState(() {
        currentIcon = widget.icon;
      });
    }
  }

  [...]

  child: Icon(currentIcon, size: 50, color: themeProvider.titleColor)
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In _MainHomeState you should do rebuild with setState (or other state management tool):

```
    class _MainHomeState extends State<MainHome>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
      late TabController _tabController;
    
      int _selectedIndex = 0;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
        _tabController.addListener(() {
          if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
            print(
                "tab is animating. from active (getting the index) to inactive(getting the index) ");
          } else {
            setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = _tabController.index;
            });
          }
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        _tabController.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          ....
                  Icon(getIconForTab(_selectedIndex)),
          ....
      }
    
    IconData getIconForTab(int index) => switch (index) {
          0 => Icons.add,
          1 => Icons.alarm_add_rounded,
          2 => Icons.edit_document,
          _ => Icons.add
        };
}
```

Also you should look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60255071/5243472)

Comment: But, to get the IconButton icon on my TaskButton to change (which is my question), shouldn't I rebuild the TaskButton instead of rebuilding the MainHomeState?

My problem is not with the tab controller, it is with the TaskButton not being rebuilt when it receives the icons from the external MainHome class.

Comment: _tabController.index don't give you NEW index every time  when you change tab. 
You should listen controller value like in code above. as an option, you could pass tab controller in to the TaskButton and listen it there in initState(..). then method getIconForTab(..) should be in TaskButton also.

Comment: Alright, I tried and works. Thanks!
Although I would like to know if I can handle the speed of the setState.
Well, the setState is done only when the animation ends, which generates some delay.
I was trying to imitate the WhatsApp button where its icon changes dynamically depending on the chosen tab, and this button changes instantly when a new tab is selected or when you drag a tab and release your finger, whereas with the current implementation, the change happens with some 'lag'...

Comment: if you take a closer look at the condition, you will notice that when true, the code block is executed BEFORE the animation, when else - the code block is executed AFTER the animation. in other words, you need to move the set state in the condition(remove else): 
if (_tabController.indexIsChanging) {
                        setState(() {
              _selectedIndex = _tabController.index;
            });
          }

Comment: Yes, I have tried.
However, when I did it, I noticed that the icon was only rebuilt when I manually touched a tab (click), since if I swiped to the side changing tabs, the setState was no longer done...

Comment: hmm.. then you could try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72295093/5243472