# Tried to get currentTab by using DefaultTabController.of(context).index but while changing tabs the current tab is always shown as 0

Tags: flutter, dart

This is code that I used. What went wrong?
While switching tabs it displayed 'current index 0' for all three tabs. I am expecting it to instead show 1, 2, 3 respectively.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const TabBarDemo());
}
var currentTab = '0';
class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const TabBarDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            bottom: const TabBar(
              tabs: [
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)),
                Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
              ],
            ),
            title: const Text('Tabs Demo'),
          ),
          body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            currentTab = DefaultTabController.of(context).index.toString();
          return TabBarView(
            children: [
              Text('Current Index: $currentTab'),
              Text('Current Index: $currentTab'),
              Text('Current Index: $currentTab'),
            ],
          );
          }
                        )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is only one current tab, so when you do

```
Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  currentTab = DefaultTabController.of(context).index.toString();
  return TabBarView(
    children: [
      Text('Current Index: $currentTab'),
      Text('Current Index: $currentTab'),
      Text('Current Index: $currentTab'),
    ],
  );
})
```

this will display the value of the current tab for all the three tabs. You probably want to do a for-loop:

```
Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  final TabController controller = DefaultTabController.of(context);
  return TabBarView(
    children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < controller.length; i++)
        Text('Current Index: $i'),
    ],
  );
})
```

Comment: Isnt DefaultTabController.of(context).index supposed to return the current active tab? If not how do I get that? My goal is to be able to know which tab is open by the user.

Comment: Yes, it is. But when the user selects a new tab, the parent widget of your TabBarView does not get updated automatically, so in your original approach this will keep showing the index of the first tab loaded. If you just want to display the current tab index as a Text as you're doing currently, use a for-loop and access the current tab through the `i` variable. If you need something more complex, [you should use a `TabController` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53826661/9997212) and use the `index` property.